# Covert string element inside of string arraylist to int? (java)

Tags: java

Suppose there is an arraylist

```
      List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>;
        newList.add("0");

        int compare =4; // the variable that I wanna compare with that "0"
```

Now What if I want to compare with a variable called, compare =4 ; with that "0"?

How can I convert string element that inside of arraylist to int??

I know how array works but not arraylist.

Comment: Use Integer.parseInt() to convert "0" into integer then compare Integer.parseInt("0")==4

Comment: To convert all elements inside ArrayList to integer .. `List<Integer> intList= stringList.stream().map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: No I want like specific index.

Comment: Like specific index of string to int. Assume that not all of string doesnt express the int

Comment: How to use integer.pasreint for arraylist index?

Comment: `int index = 0;
  if(Integer.parseInt(stringList.get(index))==4){}`

Comment: It threw me the error tho.

Comment: check my answer to match full code

Comment: Hey, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

use [ArrayList.get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-) to get the item. Then use [Integer.parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) to convert `String` to `Integer`

`int integerInsideArrayList = Integer.parseInt(newList.get(0));`

Answer (score 0):

#### Try to use the Integer method to convert it into integer and compare

```
Integer.parseInt(num);
```

Comment: You didn't add a full answer. The OP was asking about how to do it with an arraylist.

Comment: Instead of making a remark about how a search might find it - even if it has merit -, it is better to do the search and provide a link (perhaps even to the search results). It sometimes happens that searching and finding information on a topic is not quite as straightforward as we might think.

Answer (score 0):

To check by index:

```
  List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
  newList.add("0");

  int index = 0;
  int compare = 4;
  if(Integer.parseInt(newList.get(index))==compare){

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Integer.parseInt(String value) would work.
For reference here is your code:

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
newList.add("0");

int compare =4;
String val = "";
if(compare != Integer.parseInt(newList.get(0))) {
  val = "4 does not equal to 0";
}
System.out.println(val);
```